# Duplicate results from function applied to DataFrame using groupby

Tags: python, pandas, function, dataframe, analysis

I am trying to calculate the percentage of income groups that are in debt compared to the total of individuals in those income groups (in debt = 1, no debt = 0)
I've also tried the groupby() method but did not manage to make it work.
This is what I've typed:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
credit_scoring = pd.read_csv('/datasets/credit_scoring_eng.csv')

in_debt = credit_scoring[credit_scoring['debt'] == 1]['income_group'].value_counts()
total = credit_scoring['income_group'].value_counts()
print(in_debt)
print(total)

def percentage_of_debt(incomegroup):
    calc = in_debt / total * 100
    return calc

credit_scoring.groupby('income_group')['debt'].apply(percentage_of_debt)
```

The result shows the correct percentages but it also groups the result into the income groups again as so:

```
< 20000          608
25000 - 29999    409
>= 35000         290
20000 - 24999    288
30000 - 34999    146
Name: income_group, dtype: int64
< 20000          7369
25000 - 29999    4856
>= 35000         4071
20000 - 24999    3378
30000 - 34999    1851
Name: income_group, dtype: int64
income_group                
20000 - 24999  < 20000          8.250780
               25000 - 29999    8.422570
               >= 35000         7.123557
               20000 - 24999    8.525755
               30000 - 34999    7.887628
                                  ...   
>= 35000       < 20000          8.250780
               25000 - 29999    8.422570
               >= 35000         7.123557
               20000 - 24999    8.525755
               30000 - 34999    7.887628
Name: debt, Length: 25, dtype: float64
```

I would like the output to show:

```
< 20000          8.250780
25000 - 29999    8.422570
20000 - 24999    8.525755
30000 - 34999    7.887628
>= 35000         7.123557
```

Appreciate all of the suggestions and guidance!

Answer (score 0):

without the underlying table is a bit tricky, but I think what you want is

```py
credit_scoring.groupby("income_group").agg(lambda df: 100 * df['debt'].sum() / df['debt'].count()).sort_index()
```

Is that what you are after?